# sending array to php function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

am trying send an array to php file using $_POST ,still always getting an undefined variable
any idea !!

```
var all = [];
var textInput = $('input[type=text]');
var checkBox = $('input[type=checkbox]');
var radio = $('input[type=radio]');
textInput.each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
        name = $(this).attr('name');
        value = $(this).attr('value');
        all[name] = value;
    }
});
checkBox.each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
        name = $(this).attr('name');
        value = $(this).attr('value');
        all[name] = value;
    }
});
radio.each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
        name = $(this).attr('name');
        value = $(this).attr('value');
        all[name] = value;
    }
});
var getSelect = $('#experince');
if (getSelect[0].selectedIndex != 0) {
    name = getSelect[0].name;
    value = getSelect[0].selectedIndex;
    all[name] = value;
}
$.post('test.php', all, function (data) {
    alert(data);
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        alert(value);
    });
}, 'json');
```

PHP FILE

```
    if(!isset($_POST['workF'])){
    $_POST['workF'] ="undefine";
}

if(!isset($_POST['workP'])){
    $_POST['workP']="undefine";

}

if(!isset($_POST['gender'])){
    $_POST['gender']="undefine";
}

if(!isset($_POST['experince'])){
    $_POST['experince']="undefine";
}

if (!isset($_POST['jobs'])){
    $_POST['jobs']="undefine";
}

if(!isset($_POST['location'])){
    $_POST['location']="undefine";

}

$work_type_f = $_POST['workF'];
$work_type_p = $_POST['workP'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$experince = $_POST['experince'];
$jobs = $_POST['jobs'];
$location =$_POST['location'];
```

[image]

Comment: Use `$('#FORMID').serialize()` in `data` option. :) http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: can you please post error what you got ??

Comment: @Joy , i already tried  using serialize() ,same all variable in php file is equal undefined, by the way am getting the values of input when user click on next page NOT when user click on submit button , and am not getting any error its just like , javascript not sending the values or am trying read value in php file in wrong way .

Comment: If you use `.serialize()` then you have to access the date with `$_POST['FIELD_NAME']`. Are all those `keys` your are using with `$_POST[]` field names in the form?

Comment: @Joy , yes , actually am already used this method in same page.

Comment: @Joy, thanks its working now after restarting zend studio , i think it was an cash issue ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`all` should be an **object**, not an array:

```
var all = {};
```

jQuery will do the necessary escaping for you when passing it to `$.post`, but it won't read the object properties of an array.

However [as Joy stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206687/sending-array-to-php-function#comment14712586_11206687), you're just trying to mimic a form here. Make sure the inputs are all contained inside a single form and use [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to get a string which can be send along with a HTTP request.

Comment: ok i tried as you sead i have changed (all) variable to an object then send it as $.post('test.php',all,function(data))... still cant see the variable in php page !!

Answer (score 1):

You better run **JSON.stringify()** on the dictionary, then use **JSON_decode()** in PHP to retrieve the array.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I didn't understand well, but why you don't use the html attribute like this?

```
<input type="text" name="all[nameOfText]" />
<input type="text" name="all[nameOfText2]" />

<input type="radio" name="all[nameOfRadio]" />
...
```